# security:cert import failed: UNIX[Operation not permitted] on OS X when trying to unpack ios mobile provision profiles

Tags: macos, security

In our build environment we are unpacking .mobileprovision profiles using `security cms -D -i` command as described in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3125-inside-code-signing-provisioning-profiles and https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/.

`/usr/bin/security cms -D -i our_profile.mobileprovision`

Sometimes it fails with a text in stderr:

```
security: cert import failed: UNIX[Operation not permitted]
security: problem decoding
```

Adding `-v` flag doesn't make it more clear:

```
received commands
Got default certdb
security: cert import failed: UNIX[Operation not permitted]
security: problem decoding
```

Anyone knows what is this? What can be a reason and probable fixes?

I checked SIP and it is disabled. I checked default keychain and directory permissions:

```
Default keychain of security: /Users/isandbox/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
Info about file: /Users/isandbox/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
Permissions: -rw-r--r-- (0o100644)
Size: 67472 bytes
Info about file: /Users/isandbox/Library/Keychains
Permissions: drwx------ (0o40700)
```

All of this is the same when "security" fails and when it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

This problem mysteriously stopped reproducing when I disabled parralel call of "security cmd" from many processes. It looks like security util has some racing conditions.
When this happens no one of parallel processes is lucky to finish successfully.

UPDATE: Unfortunately it was a temporary thing. Later we saw that the bug continued reproducing. May be it become less often, but it was not fixed.